# Adding enhanced grid within a titlepane in dojo

Tags: javascript, web, dojo

So here goes

I have a widget that I have created which contains an enhanced grid.

I now want this widget to have a titlePane that wraps around the enhanced grid which allows me to collapse the grid to the bottom of the page on click.

so, thinking this to be a simple task i edited the template in my widget to be the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Over one year'">
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="gridNode" id="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The behaviour I was expecting was a title pane wrapped around my enhanced grid but instead all i am getting is the grid appearing with no title pane.

Looking at the dom I can see the div for the title pane but no title pane is showing when loading the web page in the browser.

Any dojoers out there know what black magic is required for this to work?

Comment: Is your widget actually inheriting `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`?

Comment: Yes i essentially only had the enhanced grid in the widget, the widget was working with just the grid but when wrapping that in a title pane i am not getting the behaviour i expected.

Comment: Can you show the code in the widget module itself?  Also, what version of Dojo are you using?

Comment: the code i will edit to question

Comment: one thing that crossed my mind is; am i even allowed to declare a TitlePane in the templateString of a widget?

Comment: Does it work fine when you do it programmatically? Declaring a TitlePane in a templateString shouldn't be a problem as I've done it quite a few times myself. One thing to check would be to see is that if you see the div for the TitlePane, has it been converted into a dojo Widget or is it still just a regular div?

Comment: yes when done programatically it works, thankyou, please add as an answer so i can credit you.

Comment: i cant get it to work declaratively but programatically it works fine, i guess you might be on to something when you mention it not being treated as a dojo widget.